# Euclidean Geometry book recommendation

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

Where I can learn euclidean geometry from scratch to advanced level? Could you suggest some good books for the same?

Answer (score 2):

I second the suggestion of [Hartshorne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hartshorne)'s [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387986502).

There is also [Dan Pedoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Pedoe)'s [Geometry: A Comprehensive Course](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486658120).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Hartshorne's *Euclid and Beyond*.